# Need help writing logical statements for the following example

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I am looking to code the logic of the following scenario as efficiently as possible.

I have 4 variables which are ordinal variables with 5 categories ranging from 0 to 4..

1. Difficulty with Hygiene (varname: H2I)
2. Difficulty with Toilet (varname: H2H)
3. Difficulty with Locomotion (varname: H2C)
4. Difficulty Eating (varname: H2G)

Essentially if any of the options are non-missing I want to use there value in the difficulty function and for the ones that are missing I want the difficulty function arguments to be 0... **I am struggling to write this code**

It may be important to note that there is no actual data. The values I am working with are survey responses so they come in one at a time.

The Overall Difficulty Scale function looks as follows:

```
diff.fun<-function(H2I,H2H,H2C,H2G) {

  ifelse(H2I == 4 & H2H == 4 & H2C == 4 & H2G == 4 ,6,
     ifelse(H2G == 4 | H2C == 4 ,5,
            ifelse (H2C == 3 | H2G == 3 ,4,
                    ifelse((H2I>=3 | H2H>=3) & H2C<3 & H2C<3,3,
                           ifelse((H2I==2 | H2H==2 | H2C==2 | H2G==2) & (H2I<3 & H2H<3 & H2C<3 & H2G<3),2,
                                  ifelse ((H2I==1 | H2H==1  | H2C==1 | H2G==1 ) & (H2I<2 & H2H<2 & H2C<2 & H2G<2),1, 
                                          ifelse(H2I == 0 & H2H == 0 & H2C ==0 & H2G  == 0,0,NA)))))))
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am fairly new to R and struggling a bit with the logic here. I am happy to provide more details if necessary.

EDIT:

For example,

If H2I and H2H are non-missing and H2C and H2G are missing how do I tell the diff.fun to do:

diff.fun(H2I,H2H,0,0).

Basically the code before the function has to determine which difficulty components are non-missing and give these values to the function whereas the missings have to be zero.

Comment: can you give an example? you can put the vectors into a 4-column matrix, then take the first non-zero column: `set.seed(1); m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:4), 40, TRUE), 10); m[is.na(m)] <- 0; m[cbind(1:10, max.col(m != 0, 'first'))]`

Comment: I added an example which hopefully provides some clarity

Comment: In exactly what format will the data arrive? Please give example input data sets with and without a missing value.

Comment: no that didn't help at all. please read this before posting questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can set a default value for missing arguments when defining the function:

```
diff.fun<-function(H2I = 0,H2H = 0,H2C = 0,H2G = 0){...}
```

Now when no value is supplied for one or more argument, it is 0 as default, e.g.:

```
diff.fun(H2I = 1, H2H = 2, H2G = 3)
```

`H2C` is assumed to be 0

Comment: I added an example which hopefully provides some clarity